How do I split a string in into an array of strings of equal length in pure sql on Databricks
I have a column in a table with strings of variable length:
|value        |
|-------------|
|abcdefgh     |
|1234567891011|

I need to split the strings into arrays of strings, where each string is of length 2 (except for the last string in case of an odd number of characters). Like so:
|value        |split_value                |
|-------------|---------------------------|
|abcdefgh     |[ab, cd, ef, gh, ]         |
|1234567891011|[12, 34, 56, 78, 91, 01, 1]|

This works in pyspark:
# Sample data
data = [("abcdefgh",), ("1234567891011",)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["value"])
# Register the DataFrame as a temporary view
df.createOrReplaceTempView("strings")
# Use Spark SQL to add a delimiter every 2 characters and then split the string
result = spark.sql("""
SELECT 
    value,
    split(regexp_replace(value, '(.{2})', '$1,'), ',') AS split_value
FROM strings
""")
# Show the result
result.show(truncate=False)

... giving the resulting table above as expected.
However, when I execute the excact same sql statement in an sql cell in a Databricks notebook, I get an array of empty strings:
%sql
SELECT 
    value,
    split(regexp_replace(value, '(.{2})', '$1,'), ',') AS split_value
FROM strings

|value        |split_value                 |
|-------------|----------------------------|
|abcdefgh     |["", "", "", "", ]          |
|1234567891011|["", "", "", "", "", "", ""]|

It also gives me this warning:

How can I achieve the desired result in sql on Databricks?

In the SQL version try changing regexp_replace(value, '(.{2})', '$1,') to regexp_replace(value, '(.{2})', '$\1,') 

Excellent, that seems to work perfecly! Thanks!

Adding my comment as answer. I'm seldom if ever use regexp_replace but this appears to work. Apologize for lack of additional information here.
In the SQL version try changing this:
regexp_replace(value, '(.{2})', '$1,') 

to this:
regexp_replace(value, '(.{2})', '$\1,')

